# Interview Q for flattening dicts

Tags: java, algorithm

Had this interview question.

Write a function to flatten array of dicts
example_input:
example_input= `[{a:{b:{c:{d:'e'}}}}, {a:{b:{c:{d:{e:'f'}}}}}]`
example_output: `[{a_b_c_d:'e'}, {a_b_c_d_e:'f'}]`

1. How can this input be modeled in java ?
2. How can this question be solved in Java.

What kind of Data Structure can the above input be mapped to ?

```
class Node {
   String s;
   Node node;
}
```

I tried using this Node class  that would lead to `{node:{node:{node:{s:'value'}` instead of above `{a:{b:{c:{d:'e'}}}}`.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong.You have to replace every :{ with _ and all consecutive } must be replace by a single }.

Comment: @Dante The idea is to work in general. For example, this doesn't work for the case `{a:{b:c,d: e}}` since in this case you should have `{a_b: c, a_d: e}`. The examples he gave are not representative.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget that dictionaries are sets of pairs `(key, value)` with the invariant that the keys are being unique. So you could represent them as:

```java
class Dict {
    List<Pair> pairs;
}
```

where `Pair` is

```java
class Pair {
    String key;
    Dict value;
}
```

or if you want the more general notion:

```java
class Pair<T> {
    T key;
    Dict value;
}
```

Note that you can represent single values as a `Dict` of one `Pair` with value `null`. Then your flatten function void be

```java
Dict flatten(Dict dict) {
    Dict new_dict = new Dict();
    for (Pair pair : dict.pairs) {
        if (pair.value == null)
            new_dict.pairs.add(pair);
        else
            new_dict.pairs.addAll(combine(pair.key, flatten(pair.value)));
    }
}

List<Pair> combine(String key, Dict value) { //here value is a flattened dict
    List<Pair> pairs = new ArrayList<Pair>();
    for (Pair pair : value.pairs) {
        pairs.add(new Pair(key + "_" + pair.key, pair.value));
    }
    return pairs;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can model the input using two classes that implement the following interface:

```
public interface Node {
  public Map<String, String> flatten(String prefix);
}
```

The string node:

```
public class StringNode implements Node {
  private String nodeString;
  public StringNode(String s){
    this.nodeString = s;
  }
  public Map<String, String> flatten(String prefix){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(prefix, nodeString);
    return map;
  }
}
```

The dictionary node:

```
public class DictNode extends HashMap<String, Node> implements Node {
  public Map<String, String> flatten(String prefix){
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    if ( prefix.length() > 0 ) prefix = prefix + "_";
    for ( String key : keySet() ) {
      map.putAll(get(key).flatten(prefix + key));
    }
    return map;
  }
}
```

Now, the only thing you need to do is call the flatten method on the node
  with an empty string parameter value and you'll get back the flattened dictionary.